# Using gsub to clean string and then truncate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to remove some characters from a string (computer mac address + junk...) and truncate to leave the first 18 characters.

Currently, I have the following in my model:

```
def popular_locations
  popular_locations =  Radacct.group(calledstationid).order('calledstationid desc').count
end
```

That outputs a list and their count but the format needs adjustment for a search I'll do.

I tried adding this:

```
 clean_mac_address = :calledstationid.gsub(/[^0-9a-z]/i, '')
```

But I get an error undefined method `gsub' for :calledstationid:Symbol

-- EDIT --

Initially the calledstationid is stored in db (radacct model) with the following format:

```
 00-18-0A-21-44-7B:Home Office
```

This is basically a mac address plus an SSID name.

I need to strip out the dashes and SSID because we have another model (locations) which has a list of mac addresses in this format:

```
 00:18:0A:21:44:7B
```

locations and radacct are unrelated (radacct is a model where all sessions are dumped into). Eventually what I need to do is do a count of all sessions and group by calledstationid (as seen above). Then we'll query the locations table and work out the location name. I should be left with something like this:

```
 location_name     session_count
 School            2
 Home              12
 Office            89
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you put the errant `:` in there when the model definition doesn't have it:

```
clean_mac_address = calledstationid.gsub(/[^0-9a-z]/i, '')
```

What you probably mean to do is clean up that variable before passing it in:

```
def popular_locations
  # Clean up calledstationid
  calledstationid.gsub!(/[^0-9a-z]/i, '')

  # Find it and return
  Radacct.group(calledstationid).order('calledstationid desc').count
end
```

Comment: that looks better although I get a NameError: undefined local variable or method `calledstationid'

Comment: I'm just taking what was in your original example. Where is this variable supposed to be coming from?

Comment: calledstationid is a field in my db.

Comment: If it is, then there should be a method with that name and it should work so long as this method is in the same model.

Answer (score 1):

I think that popular_location is  object of ActiveSupport::OrderedHash class with calledstationid as keys.
So if I understood you right, try something like

```
result =  Radacct.group(calledstationid).order('calledstationid desc').count
result.each do |key, value| 
   puts key.gsub(/[^0-9a-z]/i, '') # formatted key
   puts value  # count
end
```

I think there is also sql-way to did it. You should select substring from calledstationid and then group by it. 
Check this article http://www.ke-cai.net/2009/06/mysql-group-by-substring.html

Comment: That one seems to delete the count value from vue too.

Comment: The problem is that I have to then use the cleaned mac to query a list of locations to get their name. I think that's why I have to do so before view.

Comment: but records in db are uncleaned , aren't they?

Comment: If there is something like seach field in your UI, than there is only one clean way to do this - add another column wich should contain already cleaned value.

Comment: As a virtual or real attribute? The issue is that calledstationid is added to the radcct table by our radius server.

Comment: I have no experience with radius , but I think calledstationid data strored in very inconvenient format. Is there way to move  calledstationid data to few columns with already cleared format? Or maybe create new table where cleaned attributes can be stored and then join this tables for such search.

Comment: I know, it's a right pain! Radius is separate to Rails app so I can't change on save. I could create a task that went through the calledstationid's once a day and saved out. Or add some logic to the radius server code to do so... Would still rather rails did it though.

Comment: Will take a look. Maybe that's the way. Thought this would be easy!! Am thinking about rewriting the string on insert...